# Find a file by regex in Golang, given the regex and path

Tags: go, file-io, browser-cache

I'm trying to implement cache busting, via the following:

- on the front end of things, I insert, via JS plugin, content hash to the asset filenames (e.g. `bundle.1947shkey7.js`)
- in the HTML file, use some template tag to create the asset (e.g. `<script>`) tags for me
- from the Golang side, have template func that will extract the directory path `dirpath`, create a regex from the filename `filenameRegex`, and use `dirpath`,`filenameRegex` to find the file and form the tag for it.

Most of this is already working, except I have no idea how best to do that regex-based find.

The regex for the file is something like `[name].\\w+.[ext]`, for reference. This works and I've tested it.

However, how to use that regex and the dirpath to get the actual file's path? I know we can do something like

```
filepath.Walk(dirpath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
 // logic to check info.IsDir(), info.Name(), and written actual filename
})
```

but there's one problem with this: **the complexity**. If I understand this correctly, this is going to execute for **every file in directory `dirname`**!

Is this the only way to find the asset filename via regex or is there a much simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, where you can customize the callback to your
needs:

```
package main

import (
   "io/fs"
   "path/filepath"
)

func glob(root string, fn func(string)bool) []string {
   var files []string
   filepath.WalkDir(root, func(s string, d fs.DirEntry, e error) error {
      if fn(s) {
         files = append(files, s)
      }
      return nil
   })
   return files
}

func main() {
   files := glob(".", func(s string) bool {
      return filepath.Ext(s) == ".js"
   })
   for _, file := range files {
      println(file)
   }
}
```